How to build a release exe for react native windows application
I am trying to build a release exe for my react native windows application using the command
npx react-native run-windows --release

But it is not working properly, it is just launching the UI but the functionalities of the application are not working. When I am trying to do the same in debug using
npx react-native run-windows

it is working properly.
It is showing this warning:
No package found in *_Release_* folder, removing the _Release_ prefix and checking again
https://microsoft.github.io/react-native-windows/docs/0.64/native-code#distribution

Please show a [mre]. What exactly doesn't work?
